# Dynamically table joining by column value

Tags: mysql, sql, ibatis

I have three tables.

> 1) **Animal**
>
> id | type | animal_id
>
> 2) **Land_Animal**
>
> animal_id | name
>
> 3) **Air_Animal**
>
> animal_id | name

```
type = (0 , land_Animal ; 1 , air_Animal )
```

I would like to retreive as ...

```
select * from Animal anm
if type = 0 then inner join Land_Animal land on anm.animal_id = land.animal_id
else inner join Air_Animal air on anm.animal_id = air.animal_id
```

The above codes are sample as I want to get. I want to dynamically join only another table depends on column value of main table. If *type = 0* , I want to join only **Land_Animal** table and if *type = 1* I only want to join **Air_Animal** table. How can I achieve it ? Don't be suggested to edit my table structure. As I described "*...above codes are sample for my problems.*"

Thanks in advance and I would really appreciated your suggestions.

Comment: tagging **ibatis** tag means I can use by ibatis tech: as if possible. If there has anyway to get it by ibatis , please guide me patiently.

Comment: I have no authorized to edit table structure in our project.

Comment: mainly I want to get is **name** column !

Comment: @Fathah Rehman P , no bro.. pls don't change because my main problem is it.

Comment: @Fathah Rehman P , as i described it is really my problem and I have no authorize to edit table structure. But I think that one "can I join both table by **OR** keywords ?"

Comment: select * from Animal anm inner join Land_Animal land on anm.animal_id = land.animal_id
**OR** anm.animal_id = air.animal_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   animal a 
       INNER JOIN land_animal l 
               ON l.animal_id = a.animal_id 
WHERE  a. type = 0 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   animal a 
       INNER JOIN air_animal ai 
               ON ai.animal_id = a.animal_id 
WHERE  a.type = 1
```

Comment: yes , you are right ! your answer is fix for my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think checking with **OR** also fix.. but I am not sure how to figure it out :)

Comment: Is there any chance to use CASE statement here ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `JOIN`s this way

```
SELECT m.*, COALESCE(l.name, a.name) name
  FROM animal m LEFT JOIN land_animal l
    ON m.type = 0
   AND m.animal_id = l.animal_id LEFT JOIN air_animal a
    ON m.type = 1
   AND m.animal_id = a.animal_id
```

or

```
SELECT m.*, q.name
  FROM animal m JOIN
(
  SELECT 0 type, animal_id, name
    FROM land_animal
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 type, animal_id, name
    FROM air_animal
) q
    ON m.type = q.type
   AND m.animal_id = q.animal_id
```

Sample output:

```
| ID | TYPE | ANIMAL_ID |  NAME |
|----|------|-----------|-------|
|  1 |    0 |         1 | horse |
|  2 |    1 |         1 |   owl |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8c08b/2)** demo

Comment: sorry sir , I can only accept one answer , but your code also very useful for me . Thanks in advance . Have a nice day sir.